# How can I create a class/method that places 4 table cards?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a card game called Scopa. To be honest I have no idea what I'm doing so currently I'm watching a tutorial video on how to create an Uno game, and trying to adapt it so that it works for my game. However I'm stuck on creating a method that places 4 cards from a deck on the table to start the game. These table cards can be taken by players and more cards can be added. Each card has a certain value assigned to it which is how players can take them (by matching the values, e.g. a 7 of coins can take a 7 of swords). I am also stumped on how to program it so the table cards can vary. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, also I am new to Java so if you could explain it in layman's terms then even better. Thanks.
Here is the code for my Game class so far:

```
package scopa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Game {

    private int currentPlayer;
    private String[] playerIds;

    private ScopaDeck deck;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<ScopaCard>> playerHand;
    private ArrayList<ScopaCard> stockpile;
    private ArrayList<ScopaCard> validRank;

    boolean gameDirection;

    public Game(String[] pids) {
        deck = new ScopaDeck();
        // deck.shuffle();
        stockpile = new ArrayList<ScopaCard>();

        playerIds = pids;
        currentPlayer = 0;
        gameDirection = false;

        playerHand = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ScopaCard>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<ScopaCard> hand = new ArrayList<ScopaCard>(Arrays.asList(deck.drawCard(3)));
            playerHand.add(hand);
        }
    }

    public void start(Game game) {
        ScopaCard card1 = deck.drawCard();
        validRank = card1.getRank();
        stockpile.add(card1);
        ScopaCard card2 = deck.drawCard();
        validRank = card2.getRank();
        stockpile.add(card2);
        ScopaCard card3 = deck.drawCard();
        validRank = card3.getRank();
        stockpile.add(card3);
        ScopaCard card4 = deck.drawCard();
        validRank = card4.getRank();
        stockpile.add(card4);

    }

    public ScopaCard getTableCards() {
        return new ScopaCard(validRank);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much I can see since I don't really understand what's going on in your code. If you can, open the video and check the description / comments and see if the code is pasted anywhere there and compare it with your code. If it isn't, try rewatching the video and checking that every part of your code is the same as the video.